# What happens with light energy of a light bulb?

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation

When light energy is emitted from a light bulb, what happens with the energy? Does energy remain around us? Is it converted to another form? And what is happening with the Law Of Energy Conservation? Is the energy conserved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy coming from light bulb is in the form of packets called photons,these photons are interacting with everything in the room.They are interacting with air particles and increasing their speed,heating the bodies and so on,finally you can say the energy of photons is getting transferred to the surrounding(in your case it is room) and the law of conservation of energy is obeyed.
I hope you have got my message.

Answer (score 1):

The radiated light carries energy. It consists of discrete packets of energy called photons. It is possible that these photons interact with matter (e.g. the walls or objects in the room) in which case their energy could be converted into other forms of energy but the energy will remain conserved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the first two answers the lightbulb serves it's purpose by reflecting those photons off of surrounding objects in which our eyes then convert to images.